# Median absolute function on all the rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, statistics, median

I want to apply the median absolute function on all the rows in a dataframe.

For a single comparison, it would be:

```
mad <- mad(as.numeric(unlist(meth.subset.2)), center = median(as.numeric(unlist(meth.subset.2))))
```

But to apply `mad` on all the rows, my code return `0`.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(meth.subset.2)){
  mad <- mad(i, center = median(i))
}
```

Input:

```
> dput(meth.subset.2[1:3,1:3])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 = c(-1.84897350463379, 4.36378679329974, 
3.29526986134283), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 = c(-2.66310030808521, 4.31912241812423, 
3.38234501345848), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 = c(-3.01334955365902, 4.39017048215191, 
3.68766066514014)), row.names = c("cg00008647", "cg00011717", 
"cg00021933"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `meth.subset`? What are you studying there? :P

Comment: @Sotos LOL legal dealer!

Comment: Ahhh. Ok, in that case try this: `apply(meth.subset.2, 1, \(i)mad(as.numeric(unlist(i)), center = median(as.numeric(unlist(i)))))` :P

Comment: LOL not a dealer, but thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use an `apply` statement rowwise -

```
apply(df, 1, mad)

#cg00008647 cg00011717 cg00021933 
#0.51927953 0.03911646 0.12909762
```

`?mad` has default value of `center` as `median(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowMads`, it's fast (if it plays a role).

```
matrixStats::rowMads(as.matrix(dat))
# cg00008647 cg00011717 cg00021933 
# 0.51927953 0.03911646 0.12909762
```